# Is there a word given to people who gives wrong or negative information to rival supporters?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word given to people who gives wrong or negative information to rival supporters? Generaly happens in sports, where one party speak ill of the other, to decrease the amount of supporters, personal satisfaction or schadenfreude. Sounds like buyerst or buy-urst.

Comment: This sounds similar to [trash-talk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trash-talk), though I suspect it is not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: @cobaltduck, it would be great if you can tell me what i'm looking. :) Have any of the two last words in the question ring any bell

Comment: Maybe a "saboteur"?

Comment: "Name the word I can't remember" questions are off topic because they do not help anyone but the asker and they are unfair to the experts answering the question. ([more](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/29/lets-play-the-guessing-game/))

Comment: @MetaEd ♦ Isn't that what a Q&A web is? where people ask questions, who set a standard here that it has to benefit everyone? Or is this a Q&A web for profound english professor? If so, than the web is missing some instructions and regulations to help guid and restrict new users

Answer (score 1):

Your "sounds like buyerst or buy-urst" leads me to believe you're looking for the word:

> **bias**: (transitive verb)
>
> to cause to hold or exhibit a particular bias; to influence, especially unfairly

As in, "She made a tearful plea designed to bias the jury."

Answer (score 0):

Not the rhyme you are looking for, but ***[mudslinging](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/mudslinging)*** is a term often used in politics that can  be applied also to other contexts:

> - an attempt to discredit one's competitor, opponent, etc., by malicious or scandalous attacks.

(Dictionary.com)